# "is not a function" error ; Trying to user Geolocation API and weather API

Tags: javascript, api, asynchronous

I am having trouble passing a users location through a async fetch function for a weather API.

CODE

```js
let lat = "48.8566";
let long = "2.3522";

  const fetchWeatherData = (async (lat, long) => {
    const response = await fetch(
      " http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key={API_KEY}query=" + lat + "," + long
    ).then(resp => resp.json()).then(
      function(apiResponse) {
       console.log(`Current temperature in ${apiResponse.location.name} is ${apiResponse.current.temperature}℃`);
     }
    );
    return await console.log(response.json());
  })();

  
function setUserLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setPosition);
    console.log("click on button worked");
  } else { 
    alert("location api not supported by browser");
  }
}

function setPosition(position) {
  lat =  position.coords.latitude;
  long =  position.coords.longitude;
  fetchWeatherData.response(lat, long);
  console.log("Lat: " + lat + " and Long:"  + long);
}
```

I have tried changing the function `fetchWeatherData.response(lat, long);`, and I have still not been able to get around the error `fetchWeatherData.response() is not a function at setPosition`. I am not sure if my error comes from the function call, or elsewhere, like in `async (lat, long) => ...`.

I am able to obtain the user location, but my issue begins when trying to pass the new lat and long as params in the async function.

Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a wierd mix of `.then` and `await` going on, try to not mix methods:

```js
let lat = "48.8566";
let long = "2.3522";

const fetchWeather = async (lat, long) => {
  const response = await fetch(
    " http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key={API_KEY}query=" + lat + "," + long
  )
  const apiResponse = await response.json();
  console.log(`Current temperature in ${apiResponse.location.name} is ${apiResponse.current.temperature}℃`);
  return data
}

function setUserLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setPosition);
    console.log("click on button worked");
  } else { 
    alert("location api not supported by browser");
  }
}

function setPosition(position) {
  lat = position.coords.latitude;
  long = position.coords.longitude;
  fetchWeather(lat, long);
  console.log("Lat: " + lat + " and Long:"  + long);
}
```

Comment: Fixed some other issues and this worked. This makes more sense. This way allows more flexibility. Thanks a lot, as this helps me understand a little more what I was doing wrong.